# css - text indentation in navigation bar?

Tags: css

at this site:

http://yoursdproperty.com/index.php?option=com_jumi&fileid=8&Itemid=34

you will see on the left there is a navigation bar that says

```
home
buying property
search san diego
   (PROPERTIES IS INDENTED!!)
```

how do i make is that that these are not indented? or at least so that PROPERTIES is equally intended. i want them to be even

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your template_css.css on line 1059 you have:

```
ul.menu ul li a {
text-indent:7px;
}
```

that is indenting the link

Answer (score 2):

According to Firebug, in template_css.css (line 1059) you have defined the style:

```
ul.menu ul li a {
    text-indent: 7;
}
```

Change that to 0, and the indentation is gone.